# How to implement cookie authentication with Sveltekit & Supabase?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, sveltekit, supabase

I'm fairly new to both SvelteKit & Supabase and have done a bit of experimentation on my own, but I would like to know what is the best way to implement user authentication with both of these technologies.

I currently have the following in my __layout.svelte file so that every page on my web application will have access to the session but I'm not sure how to implement persistent user authentication with a cookie.

If anyone can guide me and future users that would be awesome!

```
<script>
  import supabase from "$lib/api";
  import { page, session } from '$app/stores';
  import { browser } from '$app/env';

    if(browser){
      $session = supabase.auth.session();
      supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, sesh) => {
        $session = sesh;
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not clear how to do this. I tried to make it easy and put it into a user readable store:

```js
export const user = readable<any>(null, (set) => {

    set(supabase.auth.user());
    const unsubscribe = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_, session) => {
        session ? set(session.user) : set(null);
    });
    return () => {
        unsubscribe.data.unsubscribe();
    }
});
```

Now you can just use `$user` anywhere to get the session, or see if there is a session.

J

Answer (score 0):

The supabase project has released [an example repo](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/tree/main/examples/sveltekit) and [a QuickStart Guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-sveltekit) which helps by abstracting away some of the boilerplate. There's quite some modifications one needs to add so I won't re-paste all the information here as it wouldn't make sense without looking at the full solution. It's all based on a helper library https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/sveltekit

Answer (score -1):

I believe that, short of writing a full article, there's no way to give a simple answer to the question.

The new @supabase/ssr SvelteKit helpers package has improved the previous implementation but so many people are complaining about the docs that simply referring to that is not helpful.

Let's try to give as short an answer as possible.

```
//Sign up a new user
async function signUpNewUser() {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
  email: 'example@email.com',
  password: 'example-password',
  options: {
    emailRedirectTo: 'https://example.com/welcome',
   },
 })
 }
```

To clarify, the welcome page or whatever you wish to call it should inform the user to check their email for a link.

After clicking the link, the user should be redirected to the site. Contained in the link is a token_hash

```
<h2>Confirm your signup to our record shop</h2>

 <p>Follow this link to confirm your user:</p>
 <p>
   <a href="{{ .SiteURL }}/api/auth/callback?token_hash={{ 
.TokenHash }}&type=email"
  >Confirm your email</a
>
</p>
```

You would need to have created an api endpoint:

```
api/auth/callback


import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit'

 export const GET = async (event) => {
 const {
  url,
   locals: { supabase },
 } = event
 const token_hash = url.searchParams.get('token_hash') as string
 const type = url.searchParams.get('type') as string
 const next = url.searchParams.get('next') ?? '/'

if (token_hash && type) {
  const { error } = await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({ token_hash, 
type })
if (!error) {
  throw redirect(303, `/${next.slice(1)}`)
 }
 }
// return the user to an error page with some instructions
throw redirect(303, '/auth/auth-code-error')
}
```

The token_hash will be verified, a session will be created and thanks to the @supabase/ssr, you will not have to handle the cookies directly.

For more details, you can refer to the repository mentioned in my previous answer as well as the Supabase docs.

---- Previous Answer ------

While the Supabase docs are not wrong, there's enough errors to throw people off track. After managing to get it all working, I decided to put up a repo. Hope it helps!

[Supabase Auth / SvelteKit 4 Starter ( Typescript )](https://github.com/psegarel/supabase_auth-sveltekit4)